# Firebase Pagination limitToFirst Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I dont know why my limitToFirst not working. I have followed the Firebase documentation.

```
  databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
  Query queryRef = databaseReference.orderByValue().limitToFirst(6);
            queryRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        WallpaperInfo userId =  ds.getValue(WallpaperInfo.class);
                        list.add(userId);
                        oldestPostId = ds.getKey();
                }
                    Log.d("list",String.valueOf(list.size()));
                    adapter = new WallpaperGridAdapter(rootView.getContext(),list);
                    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    adapter.notifyDSC();
                }
...
};
```

I am getting all data in my list.
My JSON data (its dummy)

```
{
  "walls" : {
    "-L7miwY988GOdQKhSYZp" : {
      "artistID" : 141,
      "category" : "Luffy",
      "downloads" : 1421,
      "favs" : 71,
      "picURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/onepiecewallpaper-5e0c5.appspot.com/o/walls%2Fimage%3A87242?alt=media&token=e1654c8d-8be4-465a-a8cd-cb9075716824",
      "sets" : 7877,
      "tags" : [ "one piece", "Luffy" ],
      "views" : 9898
    },
....    }
```

I am logging keys too which giving me output:-

```
03-18 11:11:59.893 11733-11733/we_pirate.one.com.onepiecewallpaper D/keys: -L7miwY988GOdQKhSYZp
03-18 11:11:59.894 11733-11733/we_pirate.one.com.onepiecewallpaper D/keys: -L7mjSINcbL_7N7BPgP1
03-18 11:11:59.895 11733-11733/we_pirate.one.com.onepiecewallpaper D/keys: -L7ms78xdhps8LPTfWnp
03-18 11:11:59.896 11733-11733/we_pirate.one.com.onepiecewallpaper D/keys: -L7msI6VC5jzOA9489mO
03-18 11:11:59.896 11733-11733/we_pirate.one.com.onepiecewallpaper D/keys: -L7msbEs4SZwlgxgLiTu
03-18 11:11:59.897 11733-11733/we_pirate.one.com.onepiecewallpaper D/keys: -L7nq2pAl9XEQwvT-ad9
03-18 11:11:59.898 11733-11733/we_pirate.one.com.onepiecewallpaper D/keys: -L7oCUSlOo4sz974sL1o
03-18 11:11:59.899 11733-11733/we_pirate.one.com.onepiecewallpaper D/keys: -L7oCZ8u-j2aXacDN3az
03-18 11:11:59.899 11733-11733/we_pirate.one.com.onepiecewallpaper D/keys: -L7oCbQfRSmv00AWaFWi
03-18 11:11:59.900 11733-11733/we_pirate.one.com.onepiecewallpaper D/keys: -L7oCfAfEecc_4NG-0Ir
03-18 11:11:59.901 11733-11733/we_pirate.one.com.onepiecewallpaper D/keys: -L7oCjU90zMgbcnvi-Cz
03-18 11:11:59.902 11733-11733/we_pirate.one.com.onepiecewallpaper D/keys: -L7oCp5fI5HpJs6cU_Fw
03-18 11:11:59.902 11733-11733/we_pirate.one.com.onepiecewallpaper D/keys: -L7oCvejzGo8e-QHtYWz
03-18 11:11:59.902 11733-11733/we_pirate.one.com.onepiecewallpaper D/list: 13
```

Comment: You're talking about `limitToFirst`, but call `limitToLast` in your code. But aside from that, this should return six children initially. Can you maybe log the keys of the items you get, and add the output of that to the question. If you then also show the JSON you're querying (as text, no screenshots please), we'll have a better chance of seeing what's going on. You can get the JSON as text by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen check out

Comment: I asume your firebase schema is something like this:

  ` /
    /wallpapers
    /wallpapers/{id}/wallpaper1
    /wallpapers/{id}/wallpaper2`

then maybe you are observing on /, try to change databaseReference to wallpapers
`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("wallpapers")`
 and then in `onChildAdded` use `dataSnapshot.getValue(WallpaperInfo.class);` instead of for loop.

Comment: @TranDinhTung my schema is simple in root node i have only one node walls and rest are push ids inside walls and data as child inside push ids.

Comment: Then you need to change   `databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();`
to `databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("walls") ` and change listener like in my comment above, it should work

Comment: @TranDinhTung I need all day, if remove for loop it will give only one object

Comment: it will give you 6 item in 6 times firebase call your `onChildAdded` as in your limit. Otherwise if you want it all at once then use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` or `addValueEventListener` instead of `addChildEventListener`.

Comment: @TranDinhTung okk yeah, I was thinking that I will get only one object in `onChildAdded`, but I get 6. Thanks man

Comment: That's great, could you please mark my answer if it help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

to `databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("walls")`
then in `onChildAdded` use `dataSnapshot.getValue(WallpaperInfo.class);` instead of for loop.